# How to control which instance of a program opens the file?

Tags: windows-10, ultraedit

I am running two instances of UltraEdit in two different virtual desktops (Windows 10). The problem I have is that when I open a file, it doesn't open the file in the instance that is open on the current desktop, it just opens it in the first instance.

I see the explorer integration is configurable but need advise how to make sure the instance on the current desktop is used.

[image]

Comment: This is due to the way Virtual Desktops work within Windows 10.  You are simply running two instances of the program.  Virtual Desktops might someday bring the customization you desire, but they are currently, more for just organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature would need to be implemented by UltraEdit itself and it doesn't currently support this feature.
Windows *can not* manage how this works (at least with the win32 api as it exists now).

[Below is the UltraEdit documentation on the topic](https://www.ultraedit.com/wiki/Command_line_parameters#Specifying_new_.2F_original_instance).
  As you can see, there is no such option.

For worthless information as to why it works this way, I'll tell you after the help text

```
Specifying new / original instance

Use the following flags before the file path(s) to specify whether a new instance should be launched for opening the files, or to use the original instance (regardless of the "Allow multiple instances" setting in Settings » Application layout » Miscellaneous:

    /foi forces UltraEdit / UEStudio to use the original (already running) instance
    /fni forces UltraEdit / UEStudio to open the file(s) specified on the command line in a new instance
```

### Worthless Information:

- When you launch UltraEdit (or any app that manages instances), it checks for something called a [mutex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects) that it can use to see if it has already been run.
- If it doesn't find the mutex, it creates one and starts up.
- If it does find the mutex, it checks the command line as defined above and decides weather to start a new instance, or identify the window of the other instance and pass the command line to it.
- Most windows applications work this way.

UltraEdit *could* easily support what you want but it would take some work on IDM's part.  I have been using UltraEdit since Windows 3.1 and they have indeed implemented some of the suggestions I have made so it is worth a shot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Ultra Edit here. It only opens one instance and then can open multiple files in the same instance.

You can use (in Ultra Edit) an option (View New Instance) and have more than one instance. However both instances are in both Virtual Desktop Windows.

To control which instance opens a file, you would have to use the instance you want. Otherwise the first instance will be used.

Virtual Desktops are not virtual machines, so virtual desktops do not change the way Ultra Edit works.

Comment: You can open new instances by using Windows -> New Instance in UltraEdit.

Comment: You can also configure it to always allow multiple instances by using Advanced -> [Configuration] Aplication Layout + Miscellaneous + ***Allow Multiple Instances***